# how to undo "git rm -r folder-name"

Tags: git

I have mistakenly removed the bunch of files from my repo using the command,

The rm -r command will recursively remove your folder:

```
git rm -r folder-name
```

Now I want to undo the step but couldn't get through it. 
Of course I googled it before posting on here. mostly says if the changes are not committed then `git checkout -- file-name` should help but this is not working.
I also tried to do `git reset HEAD` and this is also not working.

Comment: There were some files that seems to be locked by my ming command prompt. I restarted the ming prompt and git reset HEAD fixed the issue and later checkout.

Answer (score -1):

There were some files that seem to be locked by my ming command prompt. I restarted the ming prompt and git reset HEAD fixed the issue and later checkout. So in short

1. REstarted the process that was locking the files
2. Git reset Hard
3. Git checkout